# Error : Warning: include(Mage\Venustheme\Brand\Model\System\Config\Source\ListBrand.php)

Tags: magento

Magento shows below error when i click on product to edit.

```
Warning: include(Mage\Venustheme\Brand\Model\System\Config\Source\ListBrand.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in ..\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93
```

i am looking for any trick/method which can help me debug this error, actually i want to know from which file it is coming

Comment: It may be trying some files that does not exist,Please see either some method try to call any files or not Brand\Model\System\Config\Source\ListBrand.php Please give more details

Comment: @AnilGupta padeji, figured out what was wrong.. there was these attribute of ListBrand which was got created when i installed module and was referring to venustheme\Brand\Model\System\Config\Source\ListBrand.php. when i removed that module the above error start occurring so i removed that attribute from database which fixed the issue